# Compare values given by user to values in ini file

Tags: php

I am trying to make a login validation page for my class and this is the code I have for the page LoginDataModel.php.

```
<?php
//define a constant variable for fxUsers.ini
define('FX_LOGIN_INI_FILE', 'fxUsers.ini');

class LoginDataModel {
    private $ini_array;

    //construct class will read and store an associative array
    public function __construct() {
        $this->ini_array = parse_ini_file(FX_LOGIN_INI_FILE);
    }
    //validateUser function will compare the username and password
    //given by the user to the values stured in the ini file.  
    public function validateUser($username, $password){
        if(in_array($username,$this->ini_array) && in_array($password,$this->ini_array)){
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This code will be called in my login.php page once the user passes through his credentials.  If the users credentials do not match, he will simply be rerouted back to the login page to try again.  The code for the login page is

```
<?PHP
    //check for key to see if this is the first time loading the page
    if (empty($_POST['txtUser'])){
        $user = '';
        $pass = '';
    } else {
        $user = $_POST['txtUser'];
        $pass = $_POST['txtPassword'];
    }

    //call method from a different file
    require_once ('LoginDataModel.php');
    $LoginDataModel = new LoginDataModel();
    $control = $LoginDataModel->validateUser($user, $pass);

    //if user and password match, continue to next file and exit current file
    if($control === TRUE){
        include 'fxCalc.php';
        exit();
    }

?>
```

While I believe to have everything set, The only thing I need is how to compare the values between the user and the values in the ini file.  Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

I should have mentione that my ini file will just be

```
[section]
admin = pass
```

**EDIT 2**
My code reflect the changes I've made thanks to the support from this post as well as looking back at my text book.  My problem is now that When I pass the user and pass through the file, it returns as false even though the strings match perfectly.

Comment: what will be in your ini file ,is it php.ini content or something else

Comment: See the above edit, it is my own ini file called fxUsers.ini

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the ***wrong way*** of comparison in the below line..

```
if($ini_array == $username && $ini_Array == $password){
```

The `parse_ini_file()` returns an array , so you just can't check a variable `$username` inside an array (i.e. `$ini_array`) using a `==` operator. You should be using `array_search` or `in_array()` functions as such.

Something like...

```
if(in_array($username,$ini_array) && in_array($password,$ini_Array)){
```

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion and now i am returning the error : `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProjectDM4\LoginDataModel.php on line 14` where line 14 is the above if statement.

Comment: I just gave you an explanation on how to do that. This error is nothing regards with my code. The `parse_ini_file()` function must have failed loading your ini. Can you post the full code on your question ?